# Unable to call `++` with (`String`, `Array<String>`)

Tags: mule, dataweave

I'm trying to format a phone number like `phoneNumber: "+1" ++ payload.phoneNumber` and I'm getting an error cannot coerce an Array to String.  Why does my output think I have an Array and not just a String?

The error message I'm getting is... 
"Unable to call `++` with (`String`, `Array<String>`):
    - Expecting Type: `Array<S>`, but got: `String`."

Comment: Can you add example inputs? That would help understand why `payload.phoneNumber` is treated as an Array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that according to the metadata `payload.phoneNumber` is an array. This can be either because payload is an Array and then payload.phoneNumber will return all the phone numbers of all the elements payload or because the phoneNumber is an Array. So most probably you want to do a `map` or just pick the first element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataweave joinBy() where payload.phonenumber is an array [1,2,3,4]

```
phoneNumber: ("+1" ++ joinBy(payload.phoneNumber,"") as String)
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to add

This error could happen when there is a mistake in the target expression

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map (payload01, indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
    phoneNumber: ( (payload.phoneNumber default "") )
}
```

So to fix make sure you're declaring correct

```
payload map (payload01, indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
    phoneNumber: ( (payload01.phoneNumber default "") )
}
```